# Integrate CLion and Android NDK

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, g++, clion

Recently I've found CLion. I'm trying to configure it to work with Android ndk:

1. I want it to use the ndk sources and headers.
2. I want it to use the gcc and g++ compiler in the ndk.
3. I want it to use my makefile and not cmake.

Couldn't achieve those three targets, hope you can help me :).

By the way I'm using android ndk r10e if it matters.

Comment: i can't figure this out, but does this page help? can someone explain this page to me? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360005140999-CLion-and-CMake-Toolchain-Files

Answer (score 7):

You can set up CLion to build for android by doing the following:

1. Install the NDK Standalone Toolchain (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html)
2. In CLion Preference/Settings under Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains, add a new toolchain for ARM, set the C compiler path to $NDK_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang, set the C++ compiler path to $NDK_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang++, and if you're on Windows, set the MinGW path. The toolchain tab is a fairly new feature to Clion so make sure you have a recent version of Clion.
3. Repeat step 2 for any other architectures you want to support
4. Go to Build, Execution, Deployment > CMake. Add a new profile for ARM. Set the toolchain to the ARM toolchain and set the CMake options to

> -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fPIE -fPIC -lstdc++"
>
> -DCMAKE_AR="$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
>
> -DCMAKE_RANLIB="$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib"

If you're using a Mac you will need these too in order to tell CMake to not use the isysroot option

> -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT="/"
>
> -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=""

5. Repeat step 4 for any other architectures you want to support

When building, set the profile to your desired architecture (instead of Debug/Release).

Ideally, you could specify the entire toolchain (ar, ranlib, etc.) through CLion instead of using CMake options, but I haven't found a way to do so yet.

Comment: In Preferences/Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains, you should see a '+' button to add a new toolchain. Click the '+' button and call the new toolchain 'ARM'.

Comment: i can't see ARM as an option when i click the '+' button. CLion 2020.2.4 Build #CL-202.7660.37, built on October 7, 2020 Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.34 amd64

Comment: any updates on the topic? Can you add anything regarding the uploading and debugging?

Answer (score -7):

CLion can work only with CMake-projects. Others are not possible at this stage.
However, you can use Android Studio. It include C++ support based on CLion and works nicely with ndk for sure.

Comment: Then clearly you haven't spent much time with Android Studio. Still cannot deal with anything but the most trivial NDK projects.